# How to ignore min & max value in group when calculating weighted mean by group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10'],
  ...:                    'B': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
  ...:                    'W': [0.5, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1],
  ...:                    'V': [9, 1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 8, 10]})
Out[9]: 
     A  B    W   V
0   C1  A  0.5   9
1   C2  A  0.2   1
2   C3  A  0.3   7
3   C4  B  0.2   4
4   C5  B  0.1   3
5   C6  B  0.4   5
6   C7  B  0.3   2
7   C8  C  0.4   6
8   C9  C  0.5   8
9  C10  C  0.1  10
```

I want to calculate the weighted mean by group in column 'B' ignoring the min and max value (column 'V') where

column W = weight

column V = value

To calculate the simple mean for each group considering all values I can do this:

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: (x.V * (x.W / x.W.sum())).sum()).reindex(df.B).values
print(df)
     A  B    W   V  mean
0   C1  A  0.5   9   6.8
1   C2  A  0.2   1   6.8
2   C3  A  0.3   7   6.8
3   C4  B  0.2   4   3.7
4   C5  B  0.1   3   3.7
5   C6  B  0.4   5   3.7
6   C7  B  0.3   2   3.7
7   C8  C  0.4   6   7.4
8   C9  C  0.5   8   7.4
9  C10  C  0.1  10   7.4
```

However, I want to ignore the max and min value in each group to calculate the mean by group. result should look like this

```
     A  B    W   V  meanNoMinMax
0   C1  A  0.5   9   7.0
1   C2  A  0.2   1   7.0
2   C3  A  0.3   7   7.0
3   C4  B  0.2   4   3.666667
4   C5  B  0.1   3   3.666667
5   C6  B  0.4   5   3.666667
6   C7  B  0.3   2   3.666667
7   C8  C  0.4   6   8.0
8   C9  C  0.5   8   8.0
9  C10  C  0.1  10   8.0
```

How can I achieve this with 1 line (or very few lines) of code?

Logic

min and max value in V ignored for each group would give following table to calculate mean ignoring min and max value per group

```
     A  B    W   V
1   C3  A  0.3   7
3   C4  B  0.2   4
4   C5  B  0.1   3
8   C9  C  0.5   8
```

Comment: why A V==1 keep there ?

Comment: thank you for pointing out. I edited my question.

Comment: if you have two rows with the min (or the max), would you not consider both of them or just one of the occurrences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the conditions and fix your code

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby('B').apply(lambda x: (x.V * (x.W[(x.V!=x.V.max()) & (x.V!=x.V.min())] / x.W[(x.V!=x.V.max()) & (x.V!=x.V.min())].sum())).sum()).reindex(df.B).values
df
Out[293]: 
     A  B    W   V      mean
0   C1  A  0.5   9  7.000000
1   C2  A  0.2   1  7.000000
2   C3  A  0.3   7  7.000000
3   C4  B  0.2   4  3.666667
4   C5  B  0.1   3  3.666667
5   C6  B  0.4   5  3.666667
6   C7  B  0.3   2  3.666667
7   C8  C  0.4   6  8.000000
8   C9  C  0.5   8  8.000000
9  C10  C  0.1  10  8.000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the `mask` of rows to exclude, then perform the multiplications and `groupby` + `transform` the sums. If you need to only exclude a single extremum in the case of multiple rows tied for the extremal values, you only need to modify `m`.

```
# Exclude all rows that are max or min within group
m = (df['V'].eq(df.groupby('B')['V'].transform('max'))
     | df['V'].eq(df.groupby('B')['V'].transform('min')))

# For ties, if only need to exclude the single largest/smallest:
#df = df.sort_values('V')
#m = ~df.duplicated('B') | ~df.duplicated('B', keep='last')

df['avg'] = (df['W'].mul(df['V']).mask(m).groupby(df['B']).transform('sum')
                .div(df['W'].mask(m).groupby(df['B']).transform('sum')))
```

---

```
     A  B    W   V       avg
0   C1  A  0.5   9  7.000000
1   C2  A  0.2   1  7.000000
2   C3  A  0.3   7  7.000000
3   C4  B  0.2   4  3.666667
4   C5  B  0.1   3  3.666667
5   C6  B  0.4   5  3.666667
6   C7  B  0.3   2  3.666667
7   C8  C  0.4   6  8.000000
8   C9  C  0.5   8  8.000000
9  C10  C  0.1  10  8.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, with a few more lines of code, I think that this could also work :)

```
max_per_group = df.index.isin(df.groupby("B")['V'].idxmax().values.tolist())
min_per_group = df.index.isin(df.groupby("B")['V'].idxmin().values.tolist())
df["mean"] = df.loc[(~df.index.isin(max_per_group)) & (~df.index.isin(min_per_group))].groupby('B').apply(lambda x: (x.V * (x.W / x.W.sum())).sum()).reindex(df.B).values
```